# How to Set Property from Event Handler in Another Class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, event-handling

The forms are being populated by using the code outlined in the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(v=vs.71).aspx) since there are typically 30-60 labels and corresponding buttons that are populated with the text stored in lists.  A sample of the code to do this is the following with the "stock" event handler included.

```
Public Class clsControlArray

Public Sub New(ByVal host)
    HostForm = host
End Sub

Public Sub AddNewControls(ByVal TextList As List(Of String))
  ' Calculate number of Rows and Columns that fit on the form using
  ' size and offset information not shown here.
  For Col = 0 To Cols - 1
    For Row = 0 To Rows - 1
      If TextList.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
      End If
      ' Create object and add event handler
      Dim aButton As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
      AddHandler aButton.Click, AddressOf ButtonClickHandler
      ' Add the control to the internal list
      ButtonList.Add(aButton)
      ' Calculate the top and left of the current control to be added
      CtrlTop = Top + OffsetHeight * Row
      CtrlLeft = Left + OffsetWidth * Col
      ' Set Properties of the control (subset shown here)
      aButton.Top = CtrlTop
      aButton.Left = CtrlLeft
      aButton.Text = TextList.First.ToString 
      aButton.Name = "Button" & ButtonList.Count
      HostForm.Controls.Add(aButton)
      TextList.Remove(TextList.First.ToString)
    Next Row
  Next Col
End Sub

Public Sub ButtonClickHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  _
  System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("you have Button with Tag: " & _
                    CType(CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button).Tag, String) & _
                    Chr(10) & " with the Text: " & _
                    CType(CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button).Text, String))
End Sub
End Class
```

The calling code is the following.

```
Public Class frmCategories
  Dim Cat As New List(Of String)
  Dim Rec As New clsStatusRecord
  Dim Buttons As New clsControlArray(Me)

  ' Cat is populated here (not shown)
  Public Sub New()
    Buttons.AddNewControls(TextList:=Cat)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Instead of simply displaying a message box with the information when a button is clicked, I would like to store the Button.Name property in the Rec.Cat property and call the next form.  I have never used control arrays and never written custom event handlers. I have been reading for days now and I still don't see how to get this done.  Please help?

Comment: I cant see a `Rec.Cat` property.  I can see 2 private fields with those names though, unless there is another `Cat` in `clsStatusRecord`.

Comment: Rec.Cat is a public property of the clsStatusRecord.

Comment: how does `Rec.Cat = Ctype(sender, Button).Name` not work?

Comment: I am sorry but I am still confused.  The event handler for the button click is in clsControlArray.  How does the 'sender' information get from clsControlArray to the class frmCategories?

Comment: assuming `HostForm` is the same form as `clsControlArrray` you just need a method to pass the name or whatever...but a *better* question is why are you creating the event handler (or controls) in one class and trying to consume them in another?  The Ui elements could be in the form and them pass the info to the StatusRecord object...you also need to turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: I want to use the clsControlArray class several times for several forms to create the buttons and labels on the forms.  This was (what I thought) a nice way to structure things in a control array format to keep things orderly on the forms since they are populated from lists.  The option selected with button click drives the information displayed on the next form.  Seems like raising an event in my clsControlArray and handling it within the frmCategories might work?  Just occurred to me.  Then the frmCategories can store the information appropriately in the Rec object.

Comment: First, it is not really an array of any sort - it is just a control factory.  Second, it is not an either/or situation - rather than hooking the handler in the factory, you could use the `ControlAdded` event to hook the event handler when they are added (and where the event is consumed).  Note that if you create controls this way, it is up to you to dispose of them to avoid leaks.